# Where do I find drivers for Intel HD 4000/nVidia GT 640M laptop?

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, xubuntu, intel-graphics

I just completely moved from Windows to Xubuntu 13.04 on my Gigabyte u2442 laptop.

Specs:
Intel Core i5-3210m
8GB DDR III Ram
128GB SSD
Intel HD 4000
nVidia Geforce GT 640M

What I would like to know is where I can install drivers? I presume after drivers are installed my battery life would be better, which is another issue in itself.

But yeah if anyone knows where to/how to get these drivers it would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings laptop-mode-tools apmd
```

...and then reboot the system to enable the Nvidia graphics driver.

Laptop Mode and Utilities for Advanced Power Management (apmd) are two packages to give you better battery life on your laptop.